# Losing encoding when opening and saving a file

Tags: perl, unicode, encoding

I'm trying to open a file with regular HTML and special Unicode characters such as "ÖÄÅ öäå" (Swedish), format it and then output it to a file.

So far everything works out great, I can open the file, find the parts I need and output into a file.

But here is the point:

I can't save the inputted Unicode data into the file without losing my encoding (eg. an 'ö' becomes 'Ã¶').

Although I can, by manually entering them into the code itself, manage to both perform regex and output them to correct encoding. But not when I'm importing a file, formatting it and then outputting.

Example on working approach when using OCT (eg. this can output to the file without the encoding problem):

```
my $charsSWE = "öäåÅÄÖ";
# \344 = ä
# \345 = å
# \305 = Å
# \304 = Ä
# \326 = Ö
# \366 = ö
my $SwedishLetters = '\344 \345 \305 \304 \326 \366';

if($charsSWE =~ /([$SwedishLetters]+)/){
    print "Output: $1\n";
}
```

The way below does not work because the encoding is lost (this is a quick illustration of the part of the code but its concept is the same [eg. open file, fetch and output]):

```
open(FH, 'swedish.htm') or die("File could not be opened");

    while(<FH>)
    {
        my @List =  /([$SwedishLetters]+)/g;    
        message($List[0]) if @List;
    }

close(FH);
```

Comment: What formatting is breaking?  You're losing whitespace?

Comment: No, i meant that my characters lose their "true form", eg an ö becomes a Ã¶ and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use Encode;

open FILE1, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "swedish.htm" or die $!;

#do stuff

open FILE2, ">:encoding(UTF-8)", "output.htm" or die $!;
```

You may need to use a different encoding.

Comment: "< :encoding(UTF-8)" worked out, give you upvote for the hint although. Thanks!

Comment: If the input was scraped from an actual Swedish web page, the encoding is probably UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Alexander It was just an example to get you going :). Glad to help!

Comment: The `use utf8` does nothing useful there. All that module does it to tell perl that there are utf8 characters in your source - which isn't the case here. See https://metacpan.org/module/utf8